# Test Class for a Batch

Tags: unit-test

question is this test class writeable?

```
global class batchRelationshipUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {


        String query = 'SELECT Id,Status__c,Affiliate_Organizational_Role__c,Contact__c,Contact__r.Phone,Contact__r.Email FROM Relationship__c';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Relationship__c> scope)
    {
        update scope;
    }   
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

    }
}
```

Meaing I need to insert the following in my test class?

> Status__c,Affiliate_Organizational_Role__c,Contact__c,Contact__r.Phone,Contact__r.Email
>   FROM Relationship__c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to insert one or more `Relationship__c` objects in your test class but less objects in total than the scope size you pass into the `Database.executeBatch` call you make in the test as the `execute` method is only allowed to run once in a test.

So your test will follow this pattern:

```
// Insert say 5 rows of Relationship__c

Test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch(new batchRelationshipUpdate(), 10);
Test.stopTest();

// Assert results
```

The `Test.stopTest();` call is needed to force the asynchronous code to complete within the test.

I presume will will more logic to your `execute` method.

Also note that you don't need to use dynamic SOQL in the `start` method and instead can use compile-time checked static SOQL:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
        SELECT Id,Status__c,Affiliate_Organizational_Role__c,
                Contact__c,Contact__r.Phone,Contact__r.Email
        FROM Relationship__c
        ]);
```

Comment: Thansk Keith! i'm still on learning process :)